# iOS upload live streaming

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm working on the live steaming app that user can upload live streaming video and others can also watching the video streaming.

While i'm researching on the streaming protocol, I found out that, for App store submission, Apple only accept the app using only HTTP Living Streaming (HLS) protocol for steaming videos. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5

However i'm not sure HLS should be used for both upload and download video or it's only for download.

if HLS is only for download, then what is the best solutions (or protocol) for uploading live streaming?

Also if it's possible to use HLS to upload the video, can anybody provide proper way of implementing uploading video with HLS with Swift? (Any tutorial site, sample code, or any guide should be okay)

Answer (score 0):

Your mov file need to be converted into HLS format and store at the server, after that, iOS APP can easily play HLS streaming video, and so does Safari.

There are several ways to do the convert task. Ex: FFMPEG library and AWS Elastic Transcoder.

For FFMPEG there's lots of documents online for ex: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1

I've done a project using AWS Elastic Transcoder, working together with S3, Lambda, and CloudFront. Which works pretty good in my opinion. 
For reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/?nc1=h_ls